# Angular Break on Migration, version 2.1 => 4.1.3

Tags: angular, dom, migration

I can't seem to figure out how to refactor on of the methods in my service after migration.

I replaced the use of BrowswerDomAdapter with document injection. What really sucks is that the Documentation on DOCUMENT, is still just blank, leaving me at a loss.

Already fixed most of the breaks in this service.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import { Component, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT }                      from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Title }                         from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Injectable()
export class SeoService {
/**
 * Angular 2 Title Service
 */

/**
 * <head> Element of the HTML document
 */
private headElement: HTMLElement;
/**
 * <meta name="description"> Element of the document head
 */
private metaDescription: HTMLElement;
/**
 * <meta name="robots"> Element of the document head
 */
private robots: HTMLElement;
dom:any;
/**
 * Inject the Angular 2 Title Service
 * @param titleService
 */
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private titleService: Title ){
    this.titleService = titleService;

    /**
     * get the <head> Element
     * @type {any}
     */
    this.dom = document;

    this.headElement = this.dom.getSelection('head');
    this.metaDescription = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('description');
    this.robots = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('robots');
}

public getTitle(): string {
    return this.titleService.getTitle();
}

public setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle + ' | Stareable');
}

public getMetaDescription(): string {
    return this.metaDescription.getAttribute('content');
}

public setMetaDescription(description: string) {
    this.metaDescription.setAttribute('content', description);
}

public getMetaRobots(): string {
    return this.robots.getAttribute('content');
}

public setMetaRobots(robots: string) {
    this.robots.setAttribute('content', robots);
}

/**
 * get the HTML Element when it is in the markup, or create it.
 * @param name
 * @returns {HTMLElement}
 */
private getOrCreateMetaElement(name: string): HTMLElement {
    let el: HTMLElement;
    el = this.dom.getSelection('meta[name=' + name + ']');
    if (el === null) {
        el = this.dom.getAttribute('meta');
        el.setAttribute('name', name);
        this.headElement.appendChild(el);
    }
    return el;
  }
}
```

The issue is in getOrCreateMetaElement(); Not exactly sure what to do here.

The Error: this.MetaDescription.setAttribute is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that

```
el = this.dom.getAttribute('meta');
```

is returning an attribute. Then the next line tries to call setAttribute on that attribute.